# Defaulting a value on a spring data jpa query?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table with a logical deleted field -

```
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT 
(
  ID VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  DOCUMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  DELETED NUMBER
)
```

And I create the JPA object -

```
@Entity(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DELETED")
    private Boolean deleted;

    // other params

}
```

With a repository -

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends CrudRepository<Document, String> {
    Document findByIdAndDeleted(String id, Boolean deleted);
}
```

I am only wanting to do lookups of non-deleted documents, so was wondering if there was a way to default my query to deleted = false, and allow me to have repository searches like

```
// where deleted = false
Document findById(String id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might get messy, but I believe you can use

```
Document findByIdAndDeletedIsFalse(String id);
```

for spring data repositories ([reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Hibernate you can add `@Where` annotation to your class. Like this:

```
@Where(clause="deleted <> '1'")
@Entity(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DELETED")
    private Boolean deleted;

    // other params

}
```

Take a look here http://featurenotbug.com/2009/07/soft-deletes-using-hibernate-annotations/.